# Stored procedure couldn't execute the entire statement in sybase

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase

I have created a stored procedure in Sybase using interactive sql which compares two rows from two tables with same structure and if there is any difference in any column's data of the table then it returns that particular row.

```
Stored procedure is written as below:

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE Validation
 @databaseTo SYSNAME,
@tableTo    SYSNAME,
@tableFrom   SYSNAME
 AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(10000)
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @nameList VARCHAR(8000)

select @nameList=""
select @stmt=""
select @columnName=""

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE c1 cursor
 for select name 
 from syscolumns 
 where id=(select id 
            from sysobjects 
            where name=@tableFrom)


OPEN c1
FETCH c1
INTO @columnName

while( @@sqlstatus!=2)
BEGIN

    if(@columnName!= "rqst_id")
        BEGIN
            select @nameList=@nameList+"a."+@columnName+"= b."+@columnName+" AND "

        END
 FETCH c1
 INTO @columnName

END
close c1

select @nameList=@nameList+"a.rqst_id=b.rqst_id"

PRINT @nameList
PRINT @tableFrom

select @stmt='select a.* from '+ @tableFrom+' a LEFT JOIN '+ @databaseTo+'.dbo.'+@tableTo+' b on '+ @nameList+' where b.rqst_id IS NULL'
PRINT @stmt
EXEC @stmt

END
```

this stored procedure compiles properly but when executed using below statement

```
EXEC dbo.Validation ('fr2015_dev','fr300output_cost','fr300output_cost')
```

I get this error

> "Couldn't execute statement
>   Stored procedure 'select a.* from fr300output_cost a LEFT JOIN fr2015_dev.dbo.fr300output_cost b on  a.carrier_id= b.carrier_id AND
>   a.rec_num= b.rec_num AND a.amenity_cost= b.amenity_cost AND
>   a.circuity_cost= b.circuity_cost AND a.lost_utilization_cost=
>   b.lost_utilization_cost AND a.dest_fuel_cost= b.dest_fuel_cost AND
>   a.future_stop_cost= b.future_stop_cost AND a.s' not found.
>       ...
>       sp_help may produce lots of outputs.
>       sybase error code 2812"

I see this proc on running 'sp_help'.Please help me solving this problem .

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
EXEC @stmt
```

you run a procedure so this the reason for your error.

For run dynamic sql you have to use parenthesis as below

```
EXEC (@stmt)
```

your full code should be

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE Validation
 @databaseTo SYSNAME,
@tableTo    SYSNAME,
@tableFrom   SYSNAME
 AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(10000)
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @nameList VARCHAR(8000)

select @nameList=""
select @stmt=""
select @columnName=""

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE c1 cursor
 for select name 
 from syscolumns 
 where id=(select id 
            from sysobjects 
            where name=@tableFrom)


OPEN c1
FETCH c1
INTO @columnName

while( @@sqlstatus!=2)
BEGIN

    if(@columnName!= "rqst_id")
        BEGIN
            select @nameList=@nameList+"a."+@columnName+"= b."+@columnName+" AND "

        END
 FETCH c1
 INTO @columnName

END
close c1

select @nameList=@nameList+"a.rqst_id=b.rqst_id"

PRINT @nameList
PRINT @tableFrom

select @stmt='select a.* from '+ @tableFrom+' a LEFT JOIN '+ @databaseTo+'.dbo.'+@tableTo+' b on '+ @nameList+' where b.rqst_id IS NULL'
PRINT @stmt
EXEC (@stmt)

END
```